# How to compute the Delphi root directory for a range of compilers?

Tags: delphi, installation

For Delphi 2007, the IDE root directory can be found in the system registry at [HKLM\SOFTWARE\Borland\BDS\5.0\RootDir]. And similarly for Delphi 2010, the key is [HKLM\SOFTWARE\CodeGear\BDS\7.0\RootDir]. But what about the other compilers? If you have any other Delphi compilers, what is in your registry to point to the IDE root?

What are the registry keys to compute the IDE root directory for:

- Delphi 7
- Delphi 2005
- Delphi 2006
- Delphi 2009
- Delphi XE

Thanks in advance if you can advise for all of these compilers.

Comment: check this article http://theroadtodelphi.wordpress.com/2010/10/27/detecting-installed-delphi-versions/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Delphi 5: `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Borland\Delphi\5.0\RootDir`

Delphi 6: `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Borland\Delphi\6.0\RootDir`

Delphi 7: `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Borland\Delphi\7.0\RootDir`

Delphi 8 (.NET-only product): `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Borland\BDS\2.0\RootDir`

Delphi 2005: `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Borland\BDS\3.0\RootDir`

BDS 2006: `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Borland\BDS\4.0\RootDir`

Delphi 2007: `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Borland\BDS\5.0\RootDir`

Delphi 2009: `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\CodeGear\BDS\6.0\RootDir`

Delphi 2010: `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\CodeGear\BDS\7.0\RootDir`

Delphi XE: `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Embarcadero\BDS\8.0\RootDir`

The above are for win32 systems that use `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE` as base node. For win64 systems, use `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node` as base node.

Upon first IDE start of each Delphi version, the values are copied over from `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\x\BDS\y.0\RootDir` to `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\x\BDS\y.0\RootDir`, so do not be tempted to use the `HKEY_CURRENT_USER` based values as they are never there for users that build from a script and never start the IDE (automated build systems and building from the command-line come to mind).

I am trying to keep an up-to-date version of the registry keys [in my blog](https://wiert.me/2016/09/06/delphi-version-info-table-need-help-with-these-projectversion-for-c-builder-delphi-2005-and-2006-dllsuffix-for-c-builder-appbuilder-1-13-codename/).

Comment: you can add Delphi 8: `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Borland\BDS\2.0\RootDir`

Comment: @RRUZ that was a dead end product, and I doubt anybody is using it. But you are right, for completeness it can be added. Updated the answer.

Comment: you are right, Delphi 8 was a very bad version, but just for completeness ;)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is the registry entry that you're looking for but here's one named "RootDir" in Delphi 7:

Computer\HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Borland\Delphi\7.0\RootDir

![alt text][1]

Comment: Did you know that you accidentally gave everybody your Delphi 7 serial with this screenshot?

Comment: Removed the jpg for now, to give OP time to reconsider.

Comment: this is only valid after the IDE has ben run at least once; for users that build from the command-line, this information is never filled, so it is better to use the `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE` (win32 systems) or `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node` (win64 systems)